# Celery doesn't see tasks when django DEBUG is set to False

Tags: python, django, celery

I've got a Django application with Celery. Tasks are described in tasks.py files with @shared_task in different apps, each has its own AppConfig and is being installed (added to INSTALLED_APP) correctly.

Everything worked fine until I turned DEBUG off. Celery started to fail due to tasks of unregistered type. With the DEBUG variable Celery can see all of my tasks and work correctly.

EDIT:
My celery.py code is as following:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

app = Celery('APP')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Running manage.py check shows no errors, all config files and logs have correct rights.

What can cause such a bug?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that was causing such a strange bug was my log files permissions.

I have the following in my settings.py:

```
if not DEBUG:
    WORKER_HANDLERS = {}
    for app in PROJECT_APPS:
        WORKER_HANDLERS['file_{0}'.format(app)] = {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/app/{0}.log'.format(app),
        }

    LOGGING['handlers'].update(WORKER_HANDLERS)
```

While installing my DEBIAN package in postinst script, i was calling `collectstatic` command from root, which created all of my log files owned by root.

That's why celery failed to run: actually there was an error starting my app.

Yet strange thing is that `manage.py check` was saying everything was ok.

Be careful with file permissions on log files.